# How to return multiple Mongoose collections in one get request?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, express, mongoose

I am trying to generate a response that returns the same collection sorted by 3 different columns. Here's the code I currently have:

```
var findRoute = router.route("/find")
findRoute.get(function(req, res) {
  Box.find(function(err, boxes) {
    res.json(boxes)
  }).sort("-itemCount");
});
```

As you can see, we're making a single get request, querying for the Boxes, and then sorting them by `itemCount` at the end. This does not work for me because the request only returns a single JSON collection that is sorted by `itemCount`.

What can I do if I want to return two more collections sorted by, say, `name` and `size` properties -- all in the same request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crete an object to encapsulate the information and chain your `find` queries, like:

```
var findRoute = router.route("/find");
var json = {};

findRoute.get(function(req, res) {
  Box.find(function(err, boxes) {
    json.boxes = boxes;

    Collection2.find(function (error, coll2) {
      json.coll2 = coll2;

      Collection3.find(function (error, coll3) {
        json.coll3 = coll3;

        res.json(json);
      }).sort("-size");
    }).sort("-name");
  }).sort("-itemCount");
});
```

Just make sure to do the appropriate error checking.

This is kind of uggly and makes your code kind of difficult to read. Try to adapt this logic using modules like [`async`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) or even promises ([`Q`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q) and [`bluebird`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) are good examples).

Answer (score 3):

If I understand well, you want something like that : [return Several collections with mongodb](https://web.archive.org/web/20150108205205/http://www.kdelemme.com:80/2014/07/28/read-multiple-collections-mongodb-avoid-callback-hell)

Tell me if that helps.

Bye.

Comment: Or you can use promises for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794827/mongoose-and-promises-how-to-get-an-array-of-query-results

Comment: This appears to be what I need. I will circle back with results in a bit. @vanadium23 -- I'll check out your suggestion as soon as I'm done with Charly's. Thanks so much!

Comment: The link is broken as of 5/2018. This is why we ask you to post and answer instead of just a link. If you add an actual answer you won't suffer the wrath of downvotes! :-)

Comment: Found the content of the link: https://web.archive.org/web/20150108205205/http://www.kdelemme.com:80/2014/07/28/read-multiple-collections-mongodb-avoid-callback-hell

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ?

```
Box.find().sort("-itemCount").exec(function(err, boxes) {
    res.json(boxes)
});
```

Also for sorting your results based on 2 or more fields you can use :

.sort({name: 1, size: -1})

Let me know if that helps.