# Multiple mongoDB queries in one router.get method nodejs

Tags: node.js

I would like to have multiple queries in a single router method as follows in my index.js file,

```
router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
var db = req.db; 
var users = db.get('users'); 
var col_name=req.query.colname; 
var col_value=req.query.colvalue; 
var query={}; 
query[col_name]=col_value;    
console.log(col_name);     
console.log(col_value);    
console.log(query);

//using this i would like to populate my dropdown list

users.distinct('symbol',{limit: 10000},function(e, syms){      
res.send('users', {      
title: 'usersSym',      
'usersSym': syms         
 });
 });

// using this I would populate a table in html

users.find(query,{limit: 10000},function(e, docs){
res.render('users', { 
title: 'Users',
'users': docs  
});
});
});
```

And in my .ejs file I'm trying to do the following :

```
<html>
<head>
 //drop down list populating with first query
<select id="selected" name="colvalue" >
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<% usersSym.forEach(function(usersym) { %>
<option value="<%= usersym.symbol %>"><%= usersym.symbol %></option>
<% }); %>
</select>
//Table populating with second query
<table >
<tr >
<th>Symbol</th>
<th>Order_id</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<% users.forEach(function(user) { %>
<td ><%= user.symbol %></td>
<td><%= user.order_id %></td>
</tr>
<% }); %>
</table>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

But no luck. Wondering whether I'm going in right direction or not. If not please guide me in right way.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825166/how-to-return-multiple-mongoose-collections-in-one-get-request/29825572#29825572). It might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`// 1st fetch symbol
    users.distinct('symbol',{limit: 10000},function(e, syms){
        // 2nd fetch [users]
        users.find(query,{limit: 10000},function(e, docs){
            res.render('users',
                {
                    usersSym: syms,
                    users: docs
                }
            );
        });
    });
    // P.S. do not forget to check on error on each callback`

Answer (score 1):

You can only send data back to the client once. One way would be to do all those DB queries in a sequence, and then send all the data. Another might be to do it your way, check the status of all DB queries, and if all are done, then send the data.